# Moving quickly between aggregate and record-level data

Tags: postgresql, olap, aggregation, data-analysis

I am using postgreSQL to store and process data for a research project. I can program in SQL, R, and Python but am not a software developer or system administrator. I find myself constantly aggregating data and then wanting to see the individual records contributing to a single cell in the aggregation. The records contain text fields and I use CASE and LIKE statements to determine how these will be counted. I'm looking for a GUI that will allow me to quickly move between different levels and kinds of aggregation so I don't lose access to details when looking at the big picture. I believe the answer to my question involves OLAP and/or faceted search but would like recommendations for specific products, open source and turnkey if possible.

thank you,
-david

Answer (score 2):

[icCube](http://www.icCube.com) is not open source but allow for going from the big picture to the details (either via drilldown or drillthrough). Depending on your PostgreSQL model the work to setup the cube model might be [minimal](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/walkthrough/walkthrough.html). Note once the model has been setup you've the full power of MDX analysis for more challenging requests.

Comment: Thank you. I had looked at icCube but was concerned that the community edition does not take advantage of multiple CPUs. Do you know if this means it will not take advantage of multiple cores on a single chip?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you don't want to lose any of your detailed data, to allow for the *drill-down* OLAP operation.

In a data warehouse, the *grain* of say, customer orders, would be `order line item`, ie the most detailed.

What you should do is to figure out which aggregates to pre-calculate, and use a tool to do automate that for you. The aggregated data would go in its own tables.

A smart OLAP cube will realize when you should use an aggregate and re-write your query to use the aggregated data instead.

Check out Pentaho Aggregation Designer, as well as Mondrian OLAP server/Saiku pivot tables. All FOSS.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Power Pivot from Microsoft is a tool that would be right for you. For Excel 2010, it is a plugin that you can download free of charge from Microsoft. For Excel 2013 and Excel as part of Office365 (the cloud based MS Office), it is already contained. Older versions of Excel are not supported. The tool is an OLAP solution aimed to be used by business users without support from IT staff. Data is saved in the Excel workbook in an internal, compressed format optimized for fast analysis (millions of rows are not a problem), and you use a formula language very much like that used within standard Excel to define calculations, while you analyze the data script free with point and click pivot tables.